# swagger codegen R client data model structure

Tags: r, swagger-codegen

I have been tasked with investigating swagger codegen to create python and R based clients from a rest API. Part of the test involved creating an API that returns a list of elements as a json string, which the client then consumes and deserializes into the swagger generated model.

The python client works as expected, the result of the call is a list of these elements. The R client consumes the content of the rest call, however, the resulting model is somewhat unexpected. Unfortunately I don't have much experience with R, so not sure if this is just the standard way of representing data in this languages.

Using the pet store example that can be found in the swagger-codegen github project, the getPetsByStatus call is returning the following json:

```
[
  {
    photoUrls: [
      "photoUrls",
      "photoUrls"
    ],
    name: "doggie",
    id: 0,
    category: {
      name: "name",
      id: 6
    },
    tags: [
      {
        name: "name",
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: "name",
        id: 1
      }
    ],
    status: "available"
  },
  {
    photoUrls: [
      "photoUrls",
      "photoUrls"
    ],
    name: "doggie",
    id: 0,
    category: {
      name: "name",
      id: 6
    },
    tags: [
      {
        name: "name",
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: "name",
        id: 1
      }
    ],
    status: "available"
  }
]
```

In the R client this returns what seems to be one instance of Pet, which has vectors of fields, rather than just a vector of Pets:

[image]

I suppose the question is whether this is a standard R way to represent the data, or if this swagger code generator is using its own non-standard structure.